# What do you want our final domain name to be?

Tags: discussion, domain-name

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name webmasters.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

I assume when we get out of the beta we will get a .com domain name; do you have any suggestions?

---

#### Please follow these guidelines:

- **Check to see if the domain is taken or squatted *before* making the name suggestion.** Squatted and taken names, however clever, are not helpful. You can use [whois.net](http://whois.net) to check availability.
- **Post one domain per answer.** This makes the voting process much easier. If domains are very similar (e.g. "webapp" and "webapps"), they can be in the same answer.
- **Make sure the domain wasn't already suggested.** To search within this question, use a search query such as: `inquestion:108 "example.com"` replacing `example.com` with the domain to search for.

We need this soon so we can submit the final domain to DMOZ.

Comment: I assume the same rules as on the webapps forum apply - no squatted domain names, etc

Comment: @Farseeker: yes, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: You might want to link to http://www.whois.net/ or something

Comment: Question: Will the domain name be matching the final site name? Or will the site continue to be "Pro Webmasters"?

Comment: This is getting ridiculous, there are too many people downvoting everything in site without coming up with better suggestions.

Comment: @Kinopiko - we need to come up with something, or SE will come up with something for us if and when we reach that point. Meta is all about opinions, and those opinions matter. In this case it is better to have someone spend a few seconds to say "Yeah!" or "Nah" rather than no involvement at all. I feel your frustration, trust me, I do .. but voting is voting on some questions.

Comment: @Tim, I've seen some absolutally terrible answers on the other sites being voted to top place. It's amazing what what comes out of the community sometimes (and not always in a good way). At least our top *n* aren't too bad :) (except for the 404 one, no offense but I realllly don't like the negative branding)

Comment: I hate to even think of a domain, because if its good and not taken I'd buy it for myself. (..well 'cuz I like it, duh.)

Answer (score 15):

### WebmasterAnswers.com

Comment: This is my current favourite.  Not especially cool, but very clear.

Comment: Simple and effective, I like :)

Comment: Definitely my favourite now. Simple and self explanatory.

Comment: I was actually surprised that it wasn't taken yet.

Comment: I like it, its clear.

Comment: -1 Sorry I favor something a little more clever.

Comment: @citadelgrad - I'll be the first to admit, it's a little more peanut-butter-and-jelly than anchovy-banana-and-pickle, but sometimes exotic isn't always better.

Comment: Of all the ideas (that meet the selection criteria) so far, this is by far my favorite.

Comment: +1 for a straightforward name. Clever isn't necessary, clarity is.

Comment: -1 Way too boring.  Doesn't sound like an SE family site at all.  SE family sites have clever names!

Answer (score 14):

In keeping with the "fail" theme of stack overflow/server fault how about:

### 404response.com

Comment: response500.com is also available.

Comment: Something about having a domain name begin with a digit just feels ... *off* to me.

Comment: @Kris - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/774/are-there-any-downsides-to-starting-a-domain-name-with-a-digit

Comment: bleah, please don't feel any obligation to keep with the "fail" theme

Comment: Is 404notfound.com available?

Comment: we can't use this one, if the site gets a real 404 it will implode ;)

Comment: or maybe 200response.com :)

Comment: Personally I think something like `http200.com` (instead of `200response`) flows off the tongue better. Similarly for `http404.com` and other error codes. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: domains that start with a number, seem to PageRank lower I've noticed.

Comment: i like the fail theme but it's a theme so i don't feel bad stealing it for my own answer: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18/what-do-you-want-our-final-domain-name-to-be/278#278

Answer (score 9):

It is [**for sale**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/). Not entirely sure if I like it myself but it has a certain something about it...

## Webmastered.com

Comment: Worth mentioning, at least :)

Comment: now that i've come back and scrolled through them all this is my favorite

Comment: This is my favorite!

Answer (score 5):

## httpcookie.com

Comment: That's easy to remember, on topic and seems short enough. +1.

Comment: I don't really like this name but until something better comes along....

Comment: Well, others seem kind of fond of it :)

Comment: "http://httpcookie.com" seems a bit confusing.

Comment: I'm surprised this has been voted up so much, it doesn't really make sense as a site name IMO.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: This idea comes from the line HTTP_COOKIE, the way that cookies are represented inside a web program. This may make more sense to programmers than webmasters. Anyway a name which takes a lot of explanation is probably not a good name.

Comment: @Kinopiko I think all good webmasters are perfectly aware what a HTTP cookie is - as am I! But just naming the site after an object relevant to webmasters doesn't make a good name. It would be like calling the site "css.com".

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: I'm sure they're aware of what a cookie is, but the name is actually from a specific programming term. Anyway this was one of many suggestions I made, most of them seem to get voted into oblivion, but for some reason (lack of anything better?) this one survived and got some upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

## 301moved.com

(available)

Comment: We should get that one and redirect it to 404response.com

Answer (score 5):

I own

## www.ctrlrefresh.com

which I'd be happy to donate if it's considered a worthy domain.

Comment: I've got a mental block.  Can't ever remember if it's ctrl-refresh or shift-refresh (so I just hold down both!) .  This would at least help me remember :)

Comment: Sorry but this has nothing to do with webmasters, absolutely nothing. It's a terrible name.

Comment: @Jason: Don't know what fancy keyboard you're using that has a "Refresh" button, but normally it's F5 or Ctrl+R to refresh the page, or Ctrl+F5 to completely reload (i.e. ignoring the cache).

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: the refresh button here means the "reload" button on the browser, the button with a circled arrow. What it has to do with webmasters I have no idea.

Comment: Kinopiko: As a Webmaster, are you telling me you've never had to drill it into a stakeholder/users brain how to ctrl-refresh a page when they're not seeing changes you've made? Here at work, we've got a dedicated help-page explaining it to users because we got so sick of explaining it ;)

Plus, I wasn't saying it was the "best" suggestion, it's just one of the webdev-orientated domain names i've got spare that i'm willing to donate, hence my "...if it's considered a worthy domain" statement in the original post :)

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat what Kinopiko said.  I can't reach the F5 button ;)

Comment: I don't think it's a good domain because it's problematic to communicate the domain verbally.

Comment: @Jason: Sorry I didn't realize your keyboard was over a metre long :p  @Kinopiko: Hmm, I never understood ctrl+click actions, for me it's either keyboard or mouse, not both simultaneously.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat lol, yeah, and my elbow is stapled to my armrest!  I use both in combination way more than I should, which will likely bite me in the ass (or wrist) with RSI.

Answer (score 5):

## response200.com

Similar to others suggested here, but not as pessimistic.

Comment: Definitely. Let's have names of success, not failure!

Answer (score 4):

## PingUs.com

Available... at least *something* from the command line would be cool

Answer (score 3):

### httpmethods.com

(available) getting away from the failure theme... shout out to httpcookie :)

Comment: Oh well, I thought the double meaning (methods = get/post/put/delete, methods = ways of doing the web) was clever...

Comment: This isn't a terrible idea but it's not clear to me how that's going to grab people's attention; if I didn't know anything else about the web site, and I just saw the name, it wouldn't make me want to go and visit there by itself. Hopefully a really good name might do that, so I hope there is a better idea out there.

Answer (score 3):

Well if people really want to go for a http response code it should really be (twoohthree.com / twozerothree.com) as in:

[203 Non-Authoritative Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_codes#203) (since HTTP/1.1)
The server successfully processed the request, but is returning information that may be from another source

That about sums it up eh?

Comment: Well, from that angle the [202 Accepted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_codes#202) semantics are a good match as well on the long run: *The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.* - admittedly I'd associate this with the handling of [bug reports](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=bugs) and [feature requests](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=requests) on MSO as well ;)

Comment: Hahaha - this one is awesome! Good thinking ;)

Answer (score 2):

## sitetweaks.com

*Credit to [Kinopiko](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/users/155/kinopiko).*

Comment: muhahhahaha , siettweaks.com shall soon be mine! (note the misspelling)

Comment: +1 for including the word 'tweak'.

Comment: not a big fan of tweak, maybe slang thing; when I was kid tweak was associated with injury. e.g. "tweaked my ankle" :)

Answer (score 2):

Just going to throw this out there, even though it's not that great and has the potential for more lulz than expert sex change:

### 418imateapot.com

The intended reading is "418: I'm a Teapot" but it could be read "418: I Mate a Pot"...

Comment: :( No HTTP Status is as awesome as 418: I'm a Teapot, though.

Comment: amazingly that vague inside-joke is in wikipedia, not unencyclopeda.

Answer (score 1):

All available:

## httpdaemon.com

## httpdaemons.com

## httpdemons.com

## httpdemon.com

Answer (score 1):

## 200masters.com

(available)

Answer (score 1):

## siteresolved.com

Answer (score 0):

All of the following are available: Just throwing ideas around here. If you like one, pick it from the list and make it an answer:

```
mastersofthewww.com
mastersoftheworldwideweb.com
mastersofwww.com
websupremo.com
sitemaestros.com
webmastersofdisaster.com (but webmasterofdisaster.com is registered)
getyourwebsiteright.com
cookiesendersanonymous.com
```

I was sad to find that my best idea, "siteclub.com" had already gone.

Answer (score 0):

## cookiemaestros.com

(available)

Answer (score 0):

## dotcomnet.net

(available)

Answer (score 0):

## RequireAll.com

Available, short and easy to remember, refers to the common "tag" in .htdocs files (RequireNone.com is also an available alternative).

Answer (score 0):

### ForAllWebmasters.com

or ForAllWebmaster.com

Answer (score 0):

## HTTPArchitect.com

Answer (score -1):

## nomore404s.com

Answer (score -1):

## 200allthetime.com

Answer (score -1):

### oops404.com

Comment: FAIL (11 more to go)

Answer (score -2):

## netorgcom.net

(available)

The .net TLD doesn't seem *that* bad for this site.

Answer (score -2):

### httpchocolatechip.com

Silly pun inspired by "httpcookie.com"... sure, not the greatest idea, but I figured it couldn't hurt to post it.

Comment: That would be a good idea for the Cooking Site, not Pro Webmaster.

Comment: They'd be pretty confused by the "http" part though. whenever I see "cookie" I always think "chocolate chip"... guess it's just me.

Comment: httpbiscuit.com would be more concise.

Answer (score -3):

## ProWebMonkeys.com

Comment: It's a funny name, but I'm scared of upvoting things.

Comment: Too much overlap with webmonkey.com, IMO.

Comment: Agree, too similar to webmonkey. Though I otherwise like it.

Answer (score -3):

### comdotcomnet.com

### comdotcomnet.net

### netdotnetcom.com

### netdotnetcom.net

(all currently available)

Probably too symmetrical.  But incorporating one or more common TLDs into the domain name could be interesting, nevertheless.

Comment: Just try spelling that to someone over the phone

Comment: Hilarious, but awful

Comment: I think using the maximum 127 characters in a domain name would almost be easier.

Comment: rofl! hilarious

Answer (score -3):

### IOwnWebsite.com

or WeOwnWebsite.com